# what would be best way to convert List of ArrayList<Object> to a custom object java11 Spring boot 2.1

Tags: java, arraylist

I have List of ArrayList of Objects where objects could be text,BigDecimal, Long

```
List<Object> data = {
{"date","prize1","cardsNumers","cardObtained","totalCards","anotherPrize"},
{"2020-05-01",435345.67,43,56,67,345345345},
{"2020-03-01",45656.2,34,67,23,456456},
{"2020-02-01",56565,34,56,67,878987}
}
```

1st, 2nd ,3rd and so on objects in arrayList are the values for each filed mentioned in the 0th arraylist. in table representation as below,

[image]

I would like to take sum of each filed from above and assign to the same field of the below custom Object,

```
public class SumObject {

private Date date;
private BigDecimal sumPrize1;
private BigDecimal sumCardsNumers;
private long sumCardObtained;
private long sumTotalCards;
private long sumAnotherPrize;
}
```

I achieved this by traversing arrayList in the List,and obtained value by get(index) method.
But I would like to know if there is any other good way this can be done.

If anyone has any suggestion, kindly post the answer or give me the direction of a document which I can read through.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create factory method and pass result of parsed row to it. Problem could appear of some cell will have null value...

Comment: I'm not much familiar with using pattern so I will read and try to see how I can get factory pattern done in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's better to use the following data structure to describe a table data:

```
List<BigDecimal> prizes1 = {435345.67, 45656.2, 56565};
List<BigDecimal> cardsNumbers = {43, 34, 34};
List<Long> cardsObtained = {56, 67, 56};
List<Long> totalCards = {67, 23, 67};
List<Long> anotherPrizes = {345345345, 456456, 878987};
```

In this way every table row is described by the get(index) on every List. This parallel lists are useful for your aggregation:

```
BigDecimal sumPrize1 = prizes1.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal sumCardsNumers = cardsNumebrs.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
long sumCardObtained = cardsObtained.stream().sum();
long sumTotalCards = totalCards.stream().sum();
long sumAnotherPrize = anotherPrizes.stream().sum();
```

Comment: but in order to get data structure you mentioned above wont I need to traverse through each arraylist gather filed from same index first.

Comment: It depends, because do you receive the data in the form List<List<Object>> ?
If no, when you read the table/file you can insert directly the diffents field in differents list.

Comment: yes I do get data in the form List<ArrayList<Object>>

Comment: Yes, you have to read from the original data but I think that the List<List<Object>> is a wrong way to organize these data!

Comment: Why do you think so? A response of rest api contains many rows which are nothing but Arraylist<Object>,  I need to gather all rows so List of arraylist and pass it to calling function, this is how it is handled in the application

Comment: If you receive a json you should to parse it to a List<Object> where "date","prize1","cardsNumers"... are the field's names.
This is a clean way. It's not correct to insert a List<Object> for every row of the table.
You have to think Objecte Oriented and not row.